# In Swift, how to grab object id from UITableView and delete object based on object id?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

I don't know how to grab object id from UITableView after user select from it and in another view controller, I want to delete the object based on object id that I already fetch from previous one.

UITableView

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        /* grab object id here and pass to NSUserDefault*/

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let deleteViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("accessView") as DeleteViewController
        self.presentViewController(deleteViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }
```

DeleteViewController

```
/* Delete object happen here*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a property in `DeleteViewController` and pass the value to it when initializing the view controller.

```
class DeleteViewController {
  var objectId: Int?
}

// Previous view controller
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  // Grab your object from the data source
  let object = dataSource[indexPath.row]

  let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

  let deleteViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("accessView") as DeleteViewController

  // Pass the Id
  deleteViewController.objectId = object.objectId
  self.presentViewController(deleteViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let data: NSManagedObject = myList[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject

        let objectId = data.valueForKeyPath("objectId") as? String
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(objectId, forKey: "objectId")

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let deleteViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("accessView") as DeleteViewController
        self.presentViewController(deleteViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }
```